# Writing ¼ in xaml textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ascii

My **users** want to be able to enter special characters like ¼ in a xaml textbox.
I can do it here and now when wrting this question by holding left-alt down and write 172 - that will produce a '¼'

But in my xaml textbox nothing happens when I do this. I use WPF / XAML:
How do my user get to write special ASCII or unicode characters?

```
  <TextBox x:Name="_text"
                     Text="{Binding ..., UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     MaxLength="..."
                     Style="{StaticResource NoteInputStyle}" 
                     Margin="1"
                     MinHeight="40"
                     MaxHeight="80" />

 <Style x:Key="NoteInputStyle"
           TargetType="TextBox"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBoxInputStyle}">
        <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn"
                Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="AcceptsTab"
                Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility"
                Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility"
                Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping"
                Value="WrapWithOverflow" />

<Style x:Key="TextBoxInputStyle" TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="True"/>
     <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ValidationErrorTemplate}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ReadOnlyBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource InputBorderBrush}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource InputBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource InputBorderBrush}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    </Style>
```

I did try to google this, and found only very little information about this. One hit claimed that this is not actually supported in WPF?!?

Comment: I tried in a sample app and it seem to be working! I tried in VS 2010 with both .net 4 and .net 3.5 as target framework. My Binding doesn't have any validations and I am able to see the same data (¼) in the ViewModel property as well. There is something in you validation that is rejecting this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF will be using Unicode rather than ASCII....

According to the CHARMAP program the Alt combination for "Vulgar Fraction Quarter" using the Calibri font is `Alt + 0188`

Run CharMap

Click advanced view and then type Vulgar Fraction into the search box

When you click on an item it will tell you the keystroke.

Comment: Interestingly, when I write both Alt-172 and Alt-0188 in a WPF `TextBox` I get '¼'.

Comment: @MartinLiversage Which font?

Comment: This was a default WPF `TextBox` so the font must be Segoe UI. However, I believe that the font does not matter except if ¼ does not exist. Then it will be replaced with the "missing glyph" character.